# Opening and interacting with multiple QuickBooks Desktop Workbooks?

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to help a friend process a ton of data out of a few different QuickBooks Desktop (Enterprise) workbooks.  Is there a "good" way to handle this via the SDK?  If not, is there a way to handle this at all?

I'm trying to do this all with C#/.NET and the COM SDK that Intuit provides...

Comment: Reading your comment on the answer below...one thing you can do is Open the QB file and THEN run your program. It will run alot faster with QB open.

Answer (score 1):

The QuickBooks SDK does not support connecting to multiple QuickBooks company files at once.

You'd have to open one, exchange data, close it, open the second one, exchange data, close it, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: I only need to deal with one at a time.  Does it at least allow for you to open one, grab data, and close, without having to have Quickbooks initialized and opened itself?

I'm playing with a trial version, so maybe this is why -- but the BeginSession() seems to ignore the file I pass to it.